# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List<Job>> when unit testing a throw

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing, bloc

i'm trying to unit test a method in my BLoC but i'm encountering a strange error:

> No matching calls. All calls: MockAlertBloc.add(AlertError(type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List>', null))
> (If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)
> package:matcher                            fail
> package:mocktail/src/mocktail.dart 728:7   _VerifyCall._checkWith
> package:mocktail/src/mocktail.dart 519:18  _makeVerify.
> test/blocs/job_bloc_test.dart        main..

I debugged it and figured out it was throwed by the jobRepository.getJobs(), which makes no sense because I'm litterally mocking that method in my test.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong in here ?

My BLoC method:

```dart
  void _onFetch(JobFetch event, Emitter<JobState> emit) async {
    JobState oldState = state;
    try {
      emit(JobLoading());
      List<Job> jobs = await jobRepository.getJobs();
      emit(JobLoaded(jobs: jobs));
    } catch (e, stacktrace) {
      emit(oldState);
      alertBloc.add(AlertError(error: e, stackTrace: stacktrace));
    }
  }
```

and this is my test file:

```dart
class MockJobRepository extends Mock implements JobRepository {}

class MockAlertBloc extends MockBloc<AlertEvent, AlertState>
    implements AlertBloc {}

class MockAuthBloc extends MockBloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> implements AuthBloc {
  @override
  AuthState get state => AuthLoggedIn();
}

void main() {
  group('JobBloc', () {
    late JobRepository jobRepository;
    late AuthBloc authBloc;
    late AlertBloc alertBloc;
    late JobBloc jobBloc;

    setUp(() {
      jobRepository = MockJobRepository();
      authBloc = MockAuthBloc();
      alertBloc = MockAlertBloc();
      jobBloc = JobBloc(
        jobRepository: jobRepository,
        authBloc: authBloc,
        alertBloc: alertBloc,
      );
    });

    test('adds AlertError to AlertBloc when an error occurs during JobFetch',
        () async {
      final error = Exception('Error fetching jobs');

      when(() => jobRepository.getJobs()).thenThrow(error);

      final expectedStates = [
        JobInitial(), // Old state
      ];

      final expectedAlertError = AlertError(error: error, stackTrace: null);

      expectLater(
        jobBloc.stream,
        emitsInOrder(expectedStates),
      );

      verify(() => alertBloc.add(expectedAlertError)).called(1);

      jobBloc.add(const JobFetch());
    });
  });
}
```

If it can helps, this is my JobRepository

```dart
class JobRepository {
    final JobProvider jobProvider;

    const JobRepository({required this.jobProvider});

    Future<List<Job>> getJobs() async {
        List<Job> allJobs = await jobProvider.getJobs(query: {"perPage": "200"});
        allJobs.retainWhere((job) {
            bool? isPublished = job.isPublished;
            return isPublished != null &&
                isPublished &&
        });
        return allJobs;
    }
}
```

I tried to debug the test, tried to override the getJobs method in the MockJobRepository, to try to pass the test, but it wasn't helping

EDIT: Solution: I had to add the `when(() => jobRepository.getJobs()).thenThrow(error);` into the setup of test, because it wasn't working in the test directly for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I think that error occurs as emitted `AlertError` is not the same as `expectedAlertError`. Try `verify(alertBloc.add(isA<AlertError>())).called(1);` if you want to check the argument of the error, you can use `captureAny`

```dart
final captured = verify(alertBloc.add(captureAny)).captured;
expect(captured.first.error, error);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That would work, but I don't understand why it's not emitting AlertError with the Error I mocked there:
`when(() => jobRepository.getJobs()).thenThrow(error);`

Comment: I think that your AlertError is not overriding == and hashCode. Which of the solutions that I have provides did work, it will help me going forward?

Comment: Verifying that alertBloc added an AlertError works.

It might be because of the hashCode, but as i'm using Equatable with props on my AlertError I don't think it's related:

`@override
  List<Object?> get props => [error, message];`

Comment: The main issue is that, AlertError is trigger with the error : "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List>'" when it should've been "Exception("Error fetching jobs")

Comment: Instead of `when(() => jobRepository.getJobs()).thenThrow(error);` try `when(jobRepository.getJobs()).thenAnswer((_) => throw error);`

Comment: That was a great idea, but unfortunately it's not changing anything.

I tried adding a print inside thenAnswer and it's catching the "type null" error before showing the print, I suspect the event to be called before getJobs is being mocked for some reason

Comment: Adding the "when" into the test setup seems to fix the problem, thanks alot for your help

Comment: With more tests this solution may be hard to maintain, or even work with. With `when` inside your test, try to swap places of the last two lines. Maybe try to change `expectLater` to `expect` or even add small delay before one or both last lines and see what happens. I would even consider using `await untilCalled(jobRepository.getJobs())`. Working with Streams that have something async in between can be cumbersome

Comment: Adding untilCalled between last two lines is working great too, thanks a lot! :)